# How to pass through each file that's completed tar xzf decompression to a bash loop?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

In Linux bash, I would like to be able to decompress a large tar.gz (100G-1T, hundreds of similarly sized files), so that after each file has succeeded the decompression, I can pass it through a bash loop for further processing. See example below with `--desired_flag`:

```
tar xzf --desired_flag large.tar.gz \
 | xargs -n1 -P8 -I % do_something_to_decompressed_file %
```

EDIT: the immediate use case I am thinking about is a network operation, where as soon as the contents of the files being decompressed are available, they can be uploaded somewhere on the next step. Given that the tar step could be either CPU-bound or IO-bound depending on the Linux instance, I would like to be able to efficiently pass the files to the next step, which I presume will be bound by network speed.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in bash? Particularly if your `do_something` tool is written in a language like Python with native `tar` support, it would be more efficient to read the data directly from there; at that point the content doesn't even need to hit disk.

Comment: Added some more info around the next step and reasons to want to optimise.

Comment: If that info is intended to provide constraints about what kind of answer would be considered acceptable, please be explicit about those constraints. (BTW, no need to add edit markers -- full edit history is available for everyone to view; it's more important to make a question read clearly for folks who are seeing it for the first time than to keep new content apart from old).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following function definition:

```
buffer_lines() {
  local last_name file_name
  read -r last_name || return
  while read -r file_name; do
    printf '%s\n' "$last_name"
    last_name=$file_name
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$last_name"
}
```

...one can then run the following, whether one's `tar` implementation prints names at the beginning or end of their processing:

```
tar xvzf large.tar.gz | buffer_lines | xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 -P8 do_something_to_file
```

Note the `v` flag, telling `tar` to print filenames on stdout (in the GNU implementation, in this particular usage mode). Also note the *lack* of the `-I` argument.

---

If you want to insert a buffer (to allow `tar` to run ahead of the `xargs` process), consider [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml):

```
tar xvzf large.tar.gz \
  | pv -B 1M \
  | buffer_lines \
  | xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 -P8 do_something_to_file
```

...will buffer up to 1MB of unpacked names should the processing components run behind.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the `pv` option and see how it behaves for my particular case.

Comment: Not sure if `tar ...v...` outputs a filename when it starts to extract that file or after it ends. In the first case you risk running `do_something_to_file` before the file is fully extracted. I guess the `pv` alleviates that, but 1M of file names might be quite some time to wait. You might consider `sleep 5` in the beginning of do_something_to_file, or whatever number of seconds that is safe, depending on bandwith and/or file sizes.

Comment: @KjetilS., the 1M is *maximum* size. The buffer doesn't wait until it's that full until it starts emptying -- that would defeat the purpose (of ensuring that both components are able to run as fast as possible).

Comment: @KjetilS., ...that said, you make a good point about being sensitive to `tar`'s order of operations, and I've adjusted to address that.